# Access the Web Server Extensions folder?

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to import a SharePoint web part. A guide I am following to import it refers adding .dll files to a Web server Extensions folder in the Microsoft Shared folder. I don't have that folder. I assume I need a server-connected application for that folder to be created have IIS enabled. There is no indication that the computer I'm using ever had that folder. How is the Web Server Extensions folder created?

I have access to SharePoint and Project servers, but not those Server apps themselves. I have Project 2010 and SharePoint Designer installed. I do not have Windows Server.

**EDIT 7/21/14: **I do not have the web server extensions folder because I do not "have" the actual SharePoint server on my computer. So my question should be, how can I point to the web server extensions folder in the computer that does house the server?

**EDIT 8/5/14: **I can access the server via RDP and see the Web Server Extensions folder. Incidentally, I also have that folder on my computer, with subfolders 15 and 16, despite not running any servers on it. My questions now are:
1) What is the significance of the numbers?
2) How do I copy the extensions to the server's extensions folder if I am connected via RDP?

Answer (score 0):

They are referring to the "web **server** extensions" folder. The folder is created when any version of SharePoint (foundation or enterprise) is installed. The folder is on your SharePoint server in `%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\`. Web parts will add files into `%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\TEMPLATE\FEATURES' directory (for SharePoint 2010). For more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms460318(v=office.14).aspx

EDIT:

Here is one way to view the contents of the folder:

1. Connect to your SharePoint server via Remote Desktop (RDP)
2. Click On The Start Menu then Computer to open Windows Explorer
3. Double click the drive SharePoint was installed on. Most commonly it's your C: drive. It may be labeled Local Disk (C:)
4. Click the following folders:

   1. Program Files
   2. Common Files
   3. Microsoft Shared
   4. web server extensions

Another way to view the contents of the folder would be to connect to the server via RDP, click Start - Run (or press WIN+R), type the following into the run dialog box, then press enter:

`%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions`

If you provide the steps in the guide you are following I may be able to provide more specific assistance.

Comment: So only SharePoint Foundation, not Server as well? I tried downloading the installation for Foundation and I can't go through with installation.

Comment: See my latests edit for more information on finding the folder.

Comment: I do not have the web server extensions folder. I will amend my post to highlight it.

Comment: Every SharePoint Server has this folder. Without it, SharePoint will not function.

Comment: I do not have SharePoint Server application, and the server is not saved on my computer. So I would need to point to the web server extensions folder of the computer that does have it? Or would I need to install SharePoint Server?

Comment: Okay, I have access via RDP to the server and I see the Web Server Extensions folder. I think I misunderstood the instructions and thought MY computer needed that folder when it was referring to the server. Now, how do I add the extension files to that folder? Should I be seeing certain files in there?